# How should I authenticate my SPA frontend with my API since I´ve got no authentication process in the site?

Tags: angularjs, security, authentication, passwords

We are designing a web site for selling financial products online.

The following is a high level description of the components:

- Our frontend will be a SPA built with AngularJs.
- The frontend will communicate with an API hosted in Heroku.
- The API will expose web resources which allows the execution of the
  business process.
- The API hosted in Heroku serve as a passthrough between the frontend
  and the real services which actually do the tasks.
- The purchase process is designen to not ask for user/password or
  account creation at any point.

We have some queries we execute thru the API which returns confidential information -confidential according to the local law-

We want the frontend to authenticate to the API to retrieve this information still NOT asking for credentials to the user.

We thought about a local persistence of the credentials and obfuscating the request but that would be easy to break with a proxy so the request can be read clearly.

**What would be an option for this need of authenticating the frontend without asking for credentials to our clients?**

Comment: If this information is _confidential_ then you need to authenticate and authorize the _user_, not the application. What you are asking for (authorizing the application itself) does not solve any problem. If it's OK for anyone with access to this application to have access to this _confidential_ data also then the most you can do is set up SSL.

Comment: You want to identify the user but not ask the user to identify his or her self?  You could look into SSO, using services provided by Google, Facebook, Twitter, and tons others.